# Форма для генерации формы

Tags: javascript

Требуется на основе JS создать форму генерации формы:

- в левой части пользователь заполняет параметры формы;
- в правой части в textarea области формируются значения.

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="1" id="1" value="Один">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="2" id="2" value="Два">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="3" id="3" value="Три">
<button type="submit">Сгенерировать</button>
<textarea rows="3" id="resultat" class="form-control" name="resultata">
<form method="POST" action="#">
  <input type="hidden" name="1" value="Один" />
  <input type="hidden" name="2" value="Два" />
  <input type="hidden" name="3" value="Три" />
  <button type="submit">Спасибо</button>
</form>
</textarea>
```

Рад любому примеру кода!

Comment: рекурсия какая то

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если с использованием jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#clickButtonForm").bind("click", function() {
   var name = $("#name").val();
   var phone = $("#phone").val();
   var email = $("#email").val();
   $( "textarea" ).html( "<form method='POST' action='#'><input type='hidden' id='nameform' name='1' value='" + name + "'/><input type='hidden' id='phoneform' name='1' value='" + phone + "'/><input type='hidden' id='emailform' name='1' value='" + email + "'/><button type='submit'>Спасибо</button>" );
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="1" id="1" value="">
<br/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="2" id="2" value="">
<br/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="3" id="3" value="">
<br/>
<button type="button" id="clickButtonForm">Сгенерировать</button>
</div>
<div class="right">
<textarea rows="3" id="resultat" class="form-control" name="resultata">
<form method="POST" action="#">
  <input type="hidden" id="nameform" name="1" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" id="phoneform" name="2" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" id="emailform" name="3" value="" />
  <button type="submit">Спасибо</button>
</form>
</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Если правильно понял вопрос:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('resultat'),
  field1 = document.getElementById('field1'),
  field2 = document.getElementById('field2'),
  field3 = document.getElementById('field3'),
  btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = function() {
  var val1 = field1.value,
    val2 = field2.value,
    val3 = field3.value;
  output.value = '<form method="POST" action="#"><input type="hidden" name="1" value="' + val1 + '" /><input type="hidden" name="2" value="' + val2 + '" /><input type="hidden" name="3" value="' + val3 + '" /><button type="submit">Спасибо</button></form>';
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="1" id="field1" value="Один">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="2" id="field2" value="Два">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="3" id="field3" value="Три"><br />
<button id="btn" type="submit">Сгенерировать</button><br /><br />
<textarea rows="10" id="resultat" class="form-control" name="resultata"></textarea>
```